# Can I define a single variable function from a multivariable function?

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus

**Example 1:**

> If I have $f(x,y,z)=x$, can I let $g(x)=f(x,y,z)=x$?
>
> Is $g$ now a one variable function, $g:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$?

**Example 2:**

> If $f(x,y,z)=xy$, can I define a new function $g:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$, where $g(x)=f(x,y,z)=xy$?
>
> Is $y$ now a constant?

Is this mathematically correct?

If so, what is the theory behind it?

Comment: There exists a bijection $\sigma: \Bbb R\to\Bbb R^3$. So, theoretically, you can define $g(u)=f(\sigma(u))$. But that $\sigma$ will be a pretty weird function. I don't know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @ajotatxe Updated with examples.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you tell us what $y$ and $z$ are in advance, the expression $g(x)=f(x,y,z)$ is undetermined.

---

For example, say $f(x,y,z)=xyz$. Now you define $g(x)=f(x,y,z)$.

Can you tell me what $g(5)$ is equal to?

---

**Edit**:

You can, for each pair $y,z$, define the function $g_{y,z}$ as $g_{y,z}(x)=f(x,y)$. This is a legitimate way of defining a **family** of functions, because you did not just define one function, but infinitelly many. For example, $g_{1,1}(x)=x$, but $g_{2,2}(x)=4x$.

Some of these functions are of course equal, since $g_{2,2}=g_{1,4}$ for example. And if $f$ is independent of $y$ and $z$, then **all** the functions $g_{y,z}$ will be equal, but this is a very special case. In this one very specific case, you could say

> Because $f(x,y,z)$ is independent of $y,z$, we can define a new function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ as $f(x,y,z)$ where $y,z$ are any number in the domain of $f$.

But you can only say this because $f(x,y_1,z_1)=f(x,y_2,z_2)$ for all $y_1,y_2,z_1,z_2$.

Comment: I updated with examples. I guess  $g(5)=5yz$?

Comment: @JDoeDoe But what is $y$ and what is $z$? If you ask me "how old are you", would you be happy if I answered $15\cdot n^2$?